# Is FEMA Critical Needs Assistance taxable?

Tags: united-states, income-tax

My neighborhood was placed under mandatory evacuation for hurricane Harvey.  We have been approved for Critical Needs Assistance from FEMA, a fixed amount stipend ($500) intended to cover expenses for food, gas, and other essentials while we are displaced.

So far, our home is undamaged (except for a minor fence repair), so we don't expect any insurance claims or other assistance in addition.

What are the tax implications of this payment?  Should I expect to receive a 1099 or other form from FEMA?  Will I need to report this when I file?  And will I be liable for any tax on this amount?

Comment: When did you receive your payment??

Comment: I have not received it yet, just an approval letter at this point.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [TurboTax](https://ttlc.intuit.com/questions/3012931-i-received-money-from-fema-is-it-taxable), it is not taxable income and you do not need to report it on your tax return.

> FEMA assistance is not taxable income, does not need to be reported on
>   your tax return, and does not affect benefits from any other federal
>   program.
>
> FEMA grants for rent, essential home repairs, personal property losses
>   and  other serious disaster-related needs not covered by insurance do
>   not  count as income.

[FEMA.gov](https://www.fema.gov/disaster/4085/updates/fema-disaster-aid-does-not-affect-taxable-income-other-federal-benefits) states the same thing.